# Bootstrap: 2 column list (multi-dimensional) -> remove white space

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a 2 column multi-dimensional list with bootstrap. How can I avoid the "white spacing" between 2 list items when the first one doesn't have childs.

```
<ul class="list-unstyled row ul-pages">
<li class="list-item col-6"><h3>Item 1</h3></li>
<li class="list-item col-6"><h3>Item 2</h3>
    <ul class="list-unstyled ul-subpages">
        <li class="list-item">Item 2.1</li>
        <li class="list-item">Item 2.2</li>
        <li class="list-item">Item 2.3</li>
        <li class="list-item">Item 2.4</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="list-item col-6"><h3>Item 3</h3></li>
<li class="list-item col-6"><h3>Item 4</h3></li>
```

When you run this code you'll see the with space between Item 1 and Item 3 in the first column:
https://www.codeply.com/p/5yns5FO1aS

[Example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXwTu.jpg)

Any ideas how I can avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem by using the [masonry example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/masonry/) for bootstrap 5 (extra JS needed).

This also works for a list.

Here you can see my final code:
[enter link description here](https://www.codeply.com/p/lH4ts0jOPw)